# Cannot perform OTA update on encrpyted Nexus 4

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, exchange, encryption

I encrypted my phone because of an Exchange policy with my employer. However, to apply the OTA update, I must decrypt. But the encryption option is greyed out at Settings. I tried removing my Mail account, so the Exchange policy could just re-nable the decrypt option, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your phone after you removed the Mail account?

Make sure to also UNCHECK `Settings > Security > Device administrators > Email`.

Comment: Yes, did not work :S